# SQL Developer 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find my fault. Please help.

My code :

```
CREATE TABLE AVION 
(   
    Matricule_Av VARCHAR2(20), 
    Type_Av VARCHAR2(50), 
    Date_ms DATE, 
    NbreHDeVolDerRev date, 
    Capaite_Av  number(20) 
);

// it works

// primary key constraint - it works
ALTER TABLE AVION ADD CONSTRAINT PK_AVION PRIMARY KEY (Matricule_Av);

// foreign key constraint
ALTER TABLE AVION ADD CONSTRAINT fk_AVION_PERSONNEL 
   FOREIGN KEY (MATRICULE_PER) REFERENCES PERSONNEL (MATRICULE_PER);
```

I get this error :

> ALTER TABLE VOL ADD CONSTRAINT fk_VOL_AVION FOREIGN KEY (Matricule_Av) REFERENCES AVION (Matricule_Av)
>   Rapport d'erreur -
>   Erreur SQL : ORA-00904: "MATRICULE_AV": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

The table personnel works.

Comment: Is the errror message you provided for a different foreign key statement than the one you have provided?

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key statement has `FOREIGN KEY (MATRICULE_PER)`. However, there is no `MATRICULE_PER` column in the `AVION` table. Perhaps you meant to put `FOREIGN KEY (MATRICULE_AV)`?

E.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE AVION ADD CONSTRAINT fk_AVION_PERSONNEL 
      FOREIGN KEY (MATRICULE_AV)
      REFERENCES PERSONNEL (MATRICULE_PER);
```

Comment: it works thank you very much .
but  in my tables I see many other tables and I do not know what for. like AQ$_QUEUES , AQ$_SCHEDULE.  can you help me remove them?

Comment: I don't understand what you need help with. What photo? (bear in mind that I cannot see images posted on this site due to firewall restrictions on my end). Perhaps you should either edit your question to add additonal information or raise a new question if this new request is not related to this question.

Comment: Sounds like you've got [queues](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_intro.htm) set up in your database; perhaps you ought to find out why they're there before you get rid of them willy-nilly.

Comment: I work in sql developer and I create a table with queries that I showed you earlier .
But when I want to see against the tables that I create with sql developer I see many tables that are created automatically as _QUEUES $ AQ , AQ $ _SCHEDULE and I do not know if it causes a problem in my database.
If so I would like to know how to remove them?
because it's boring to look across multiple table to find the ones I created.thanks

Comment: is this your own personal database, or is it shared with other people? Because if it's the latter, maybe they're someone else's tables?

Comment: yes it's my own personneal database , i create it for doing my project. but i think that is problem in my sql developer configuration.i just create a connexion with system and i create my tables.is it a good way for creationg a database in sqldevelopper?

Comment: wait, are you talking about tables in the SYS schema? If so, you shouldn't be doing ANYTHING in the SYS schema, beyond creating a new schema for you to log in and play around with.